# iPython in a REPL inside vim. Is there any variable explorer?

Tags: vim, ipython

I am wondering if there is any variable explorer like this: https://github.com/ipselium/cpyvke that can be opened directly from the `iPython` console, i.e.

```
In [1]: <I call the variable explorer directly from here>
```

I am aware of `%whos` but I would like something more interactive.

FYI: I have a batch script that automatically opens `gvim` and open an `iPython` `REPL`.
I am working on `Windows 10`.
My work environment looks like this:

[image]